# Android build for React Native project failing after updating SDK Tools

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio

As the title states, I can neither run the project locally nor build an APK on Android Studio since I updated some SDK tools.

This is the build time error:

```
> Task :expo-dev-launcher:compileReleaseKotlin FAILED
> Compilation with Kotlin compile daemon was not successful
> java.rmi.ServerException: RemoteException occurred in server thread; nested exception is:
> java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is:
> java.io.InvalidClassException: org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalModuleInfo; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 1, local class serialVersionUID = 0
> at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:391)
> at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
> at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
> at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
> at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
> at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:562)
> at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:796)
> at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:677)
> at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
> at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:676)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
> at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.exceptionReceivedFromServer(StreamRemoteCall.java:303)
> at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(StreamRemoteCall.java:279)
> at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:164)
> at java.rmi/java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invokeRemoteMethod(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:217)
> at java.rmi/java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:162)
> at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy240.compile(Unknown Source)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleKotlinCompilerWork.incrementalCompilationWithDaemon(GradleKotlinCompilerWork.kt:298)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleKotlinCompilerWork.compileWithDaemon(GradleKotlinCompilerWork.kt:215)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleKotlinCompilerWork.compileWithDaemonOrFallbackImpl(GradleKotlinCompilerWork.kt:152)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleKotlinCompilerWork.run(GradleKotlinCompilerWork.kt:126)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunnerWithWorkers$GradleKotlinCompilerWorkAction.execute(GradleCompilerRunnerWithWorkers.kt:79)
> at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerServer.execute(DefaultWorkerServer.java:63)
> at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1.create(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:67)
> at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1.create(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:63)
> at org.gradle.internal.classloader.ClassLoaderUtils.executeInClassloader(ClassLoaderUtils.java:97)
> at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1.lambda$execute$0(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:63)
> at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker$1.call(AbstractWorker.java:44)
> at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker$1.call(AbstractWorker.java:41)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:200)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:195)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:62)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$call$2(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:76)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.callWithUnmanagedSupport(UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.java:54)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:76)
> at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker.executeWrappedInBuildOperation(AbstractWorker.java:41)
> at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1.execute(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:60)
> at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor.lambda$submitWork$2(DefaultWorkerExecutor.java:200)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
> at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.runExecution(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:214)
> at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.runBatch(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:164)
> at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.run(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:131)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
> at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
> at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
> at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
> Caused by: java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is:
> java.io.InvalidClassException: org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalModuleInfo; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 1, local class serialVersionUID = 0
> at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:350)
> at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
> at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
> at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
> at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
> at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:562)
> at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:796)
> at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:677)
> at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
> at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:676)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
> ... 1 more
> Caused by: java.io.InvalidClassException: org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalModuleInfo; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 1, local class serialVersionUID = 0
> at java.base/java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:689)
> at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:2012)
> at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1862)
> at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2169)
> at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1679)
> at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2464)
> at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2358)
> at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2196)
> at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1679)
> at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:493)
> at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:451)
> at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.unmarshalValue(UnicastRef.java:327)
> at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:339)
> ... 12 more

Could not connect to kotlin daemon. Using fallback strategy.
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.jetbrains.kotlin.com.intellij.util.ReflectionUtil (file:/C:/Users/kaish/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-compiler-embeddable/1.4.21/87db94500aaf883536ae8c8efdee76bdc839d582/kotlin-compiler-embeddable-1.4.21.jar) to method java.util.ResourceBundle.setParent(java.util.ResourceBundle)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.jetbrains.kotlin.com.intellij.util.ReflectionUtil
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
error: incompatible classes were found in dependencies. Remove them from the classpath or use '-Xskip-metadata-version-check' to suppress errors
D:\\Fettle\\Code\\Fettle_Frontend\\node_modules\\expo-dev-menu-interface\\android\\build\\intermediates\\compile_library_classes_jar\\release\\classes.jar!\\META-INF\\expo-dev-menu-interface_release.kotlin_module: error: module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.7.1, expected version is 1.4.1.
D:\\Fettle\\Code\\Fettle_Frontend\\node_modules\\expo-dev-launcher\\android\\src\\main\\java\\expo\\modules\\devlauncher\\helpers\\DevLauncherReactUtils.kt:9:44: error: class 'expo.interfaces.devmenu.annotations.ContainsDevMenuExtension' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.7.1, expected version is 1.4.1.
The class is loaded from D:/Fettle/Code/Fettle_Frontend/node_modules/expo-dev-menu-interface/android/build/intermediates/compile_library_classes_jar/release/classes.jar!/expo/interfaces/devmenu/annotations/ContainsDevMenuExtension.class
import expo.interfaces.devmenu.annotations.ContainsDevMenuExtension
^
D:\\Fettle\\Code\\Fettle_Frontend\\node_modules\\expo-dev-launcher\\android\\src\\main\\java\\expo\\modules\\devlauncher\\helpers\\DevLauncherReactUtils.kt:133:42: error: class 'expo.interfaces.devmenu.annotations.ContainsDevMenuExtension' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.7.1, expected version is 1.4.1.
The class is loaded from D:/Fettle/Code/Fettle_Frontend/node_modules/expo-dev-menu-interface/android/build/intermediates/compile_library_classes_jar/release/classes.jar!/expo/interfaces/devmenu/annotations/ContainsDevMenuExtension.class
it.javaClass.isAnnotationPresent(ContainsDevMenuExtension::class.java)
^
D:\\Fettle\\Code\\Fettle_Frontend\\node_modules\\expo-dev-launcher\\android\\src\\main\\java\\expo\\modules\\devlauncher\\launcher\\DevLauncherActivity.kt:15:32: error: class 'expo.interfaces.devmenu.DevMenuManagerInterface' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.7.1, expected version is 1.4.1.
The class is loaded from D:/Fettle/Code/Fettle_Frontend/node_modules/expo-dev-menu-interface/android/build/intermediates/compile_library_classes_jar/release/classes.jar!/expo/interfaces/devmenu/DevMenuManagerInterface.class
import expo.interfaces.devmenu.DevMenuManagerInterface
^
D:\\Fettle\\Code\\Fettle_Frontend\\node_modules\\expo-dev-launcher\\android\\src\\main\\java\\expo\\modules\\devlauncher\\launcher\\DevLauncherActivity.kt:16:32: error: class 'expo.interfaces.devmenu.DevMenuManagerProviderInterface' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.7.1, expected version is 1.4.1.
The class is loaded from D:/Fettle/Code/Fettle_Frontend/node_modules/expo-dev-menu-interface/android/build/intermediates/compile_library_classes_jar/release/classes.jar!/expo/interfaces/devmenu/DevMenuManagerProviderInterface.class
import expo.interfaces.devmenu.DevMenuManagerProviderInterface
^
D:\\Fettle\\Code\\Fettle_Frontend\\node_modules\\expo-dev-launcher\\android\\src\\main\\java\\expo\\modules\\devlauncher\\launcher\\DevLauncherActivity.kt:27:31: error: class 'expo.interfaces.devmenu.DevMenuManagerInterface' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.7.1, expected version is 1.4.1.
The class is loaded from D:/Fettle/Code/Fettle_Frontend/node_modules/expo-dev-menu-interface/android/build/intermediates/compile_library_classes_jar/release/classes.jar!/expo/interfaces/devmenu/DevMenuManagerInterface.class
private var devMenuManager: DevMenuManagerInterface? = null
^
D:\\Fettle\\Code\\Fettle_Frontend\\node_modules\\expo-dev-launcher\\android\\src\\main\\java\\expo\\modules\\devlauncher\\launcher\\DevLauncherActivity.kt:77:5: error: class 'expo.interfaces.devmenu.DevMenuManagerInterface' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.7.1, expected version is 1.4.1.
Caused by: java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is:

The class is loaded from D:/Fettle/Code/Fettle_Frontend/node_modules/expo-dev-menu-interface/android/build/intermediates/compile_library_classes_jar/release/classes.jar!/expo/interfaces/devmenu/DevMenuManagerInterface.class
devMenuManager?.onTouchEvent(ev)
^
D:\\Fettle\\Code\\Fettle_Frontend\\node_modules\\expo-dev-launcher\\android\\src\\main\\java\\expo\\modules\\devlauncher\\launcher\\DevLauncherActivity.kt:82:12: error: class 'expo.interfaces.devmenu.DevMenuManagerInterface' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.7.1, expected version is 1.4.1.
The class is loaded from D:/Fettle/Code/Fettle_Frontend/node_modules/expo-dev-menu-interface/android/build/intermediates/compile_library_classes_jar/release/classes.jar!/expo/interfaces/devmenu/DevMenuManagerInterface.class
return devMenuManager?.onKeyEvent(keyCode, event) == true || super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event)
^
D:\\Fettle\\Code\\Fettle_Frontend\\node_modules\\expo-dev-launcher\\android\\src\\main\\java\\expo\\modules\\devlauncher\\launcher\\DevLauncherActivity.kt:97:25: error: class 'expo.interfaces.devmenu.DevMenuManagerProviderInterface' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.7.1, expected version is 1.4.1.
Caused by: java.io.InvalidClassException: org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalModuleInfo; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 1, local class serialVersionUID = 0

The class is loaded from D:/Fettle/Code/Fettle_Frontend/node_modules/expo-dev-menu-interface/android/build/intermediates/compile_library_classes_jar/release/classes.jar!/expo/interfaces/devmenu/DevMenuManagerProviderInterface.class
nativeModule is DevMenuManagerProviderInterface
^
D:\\Fettle\\Code\\Fettle_Frontend\\node_modules\\expo-dev-launcher\\android\\src\\main\\java\\expo\\modules\\devlauncher\\launcher\\DevLauncherActivity.kt:98:13: error: class 'expo.interfaces.devmenu.DevMenuManagerProviderInterface' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.7.1, expected version is 1.4.1.
The class is loaded from D:/Fettle/Code/Fettle_Frontend/node_modules/expo-dev-menu-interface/android/build/intermediates/compile_library_classes_jar/release/classes.jar!/expo/interfaces/devmenu/DevMenuManagerProviderInterface.class
} as? DevMenuManagerProviderInterface
^
An illegal reflective access operation has occurred

Illegal reflective access by org.jetbrains.kotlin.com.intellij.util.ReflectionUtil (file:/C:/Users/kaish/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-compiler-embeddable/1.4.21/87db94500aaf883536ae8c8efdee76bdc839d582/kotlin-compiler-embeddable-1.4.21.jar) to method java.util.ResourceBundle.setParent(java.util.ResourceBundle)

D:\\Fettle\\Code\\Fettle_Frontend\\node_modules\\expo-dev-launcher\\android\\src\\main\\java\\expo\\modules\\devlauncher\\launcher\\DevLauncherActivity.kt:100:10: error: class 'expo.interfaces.devmenu.DevMenuManagerInterface' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.7.1, expected version is 1.4.1.
Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.jetbrains.kotlin.com.intellij.util.ReflectionUtil

Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations

All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release

The class is loaded from D:/Fettle/Code/Fettle_Frontend/node_modules/expo-dev-menu-interface/android/build/intermediates/compile_library_classes_jar/release/classes.jar!/expo/interfaces/devmenu/DevMenuManagerInterface.class
this.devMenuManager = devMenuManagerProvider?.getDevMenuManager()
incompatible classes were found in dependencies. Remove them from the classpath or use '-Xskip-metadata-version-check' to suppress errors
```

The problem was more pronounced than this, and several other packages were failing.

Most of those were resolved by adding these to my build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
ext {
ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.0' //use latest
}
dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
```

Comment: [Try this](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/35210). It is a general problem

Comment: Still not working :( Put it under the android folder build gradle. Should I be cleaning my project on Android Studio or something else?

Comment: Did you try this one? https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/35210#issuecomment-1304536693

Comment: Yes, sir - I've tried both independently and together. Now a new error is here with the above: The minCompileSdk (33) specified in a
dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-31).
Dependency: androidx.core:core:1.9.0.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example + https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - this question contains insufficient details to help.

Comment: [Try last solution](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/35210)